# Matching by Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
A =[1;2;3;4;5]
B= [10 1 ;11 2;19 5]
```

I want to get

```
D = [1 10 ;2 11; 3 -9; 4 -9; 5 19]
```

That is, if something in A doesn't exist in B(:,2), 2nd column of D should be -9.

If something in A exists in B(:,2), I want to put the corresponding row of 1st column of B in 2nd column of D.

I know how to do it with a mix of ismember and for and if. But I need a more elegant method which doesn't use "for" to speed it up.

Comment: @voxeloctree I would disagree. MATLAB uses [LAPACK/BLAS](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matlab-incorporates-lapack.html).

Comment: @voxeloctree I think many of the built-in MATLAB functions that use `for` loops internally do so in the C-code from which they are compiled, and are thus much more efficient at it than using `for` loops directly in MATLAB. This comes from the fact that MATLAB is an interpreted language, and has to be compiled down to something the processor can deal with every time it is run. These built in functions are already optimized for the processor, whereas a MATLAB `for` loop may not be.

Comment: @voxeloctree Many built in functions use loops in the underlying C code, but `for` loops in Matlab are dog slow and should be avoided. Not to mention `while` loops. There is a reason `cellfun` and `arrayfun` are so much faster than manual looping. Also, built in functions are able to use SIMD instructions, Matlab code can't. In short, you're giving bad advice.

Comment: @kevlar Maybe I am a bit wrong, but GPU/parallel computing is NOT general programming but a whole different beast. And even in parallel computing you occasionally need `for` loops. @Engineero good points, @KitsuneYMG thinking about a problem fully and solving a problem in a bad way and then trying to optimize it is never bad advice, but seeing as the OP already did so maybe you are right. I would edit my comment but seeing as how you all already did so, I don't think that is necessary :)

Comment: Alright alright gang, I'll remove my bad advice. The OP is probably using MATLAB for these high-level features anyways.

Comment: Wow unexpectedly many valuable discussions about unexpected topic have been posted. I thank everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how efficient this solution is, but it avoids using any loops so at least it would be a place to start:

```
D = [A -9*ones(size(A))];           % initialize your result
[tf, idx] = ismember(A, B(:,2));    % get indices of matching elements
idx(idx==0) = [];                   % trim the zeros
D(find(tf),2) = B(idx,1);           % set the matching entries in D to the appropriate entries in B

disp(E)
```

You allocate your matrix ahead of time to save time later on (building up matrices dynamically is really slow in MATLAB). The `ismember` call is returning the true-false vector `tf` showing which elements of `A` correspond to something in `B`, as well as the associated index of what they correspond to in `idx`. The problem with `idx` is that it contains a zero any time `ft` is zero, which is why we have the line `idx(idx==0) = [];` to clear out these zeros. Finally, `find(tf)` is used to get the indices associated with a match on the destination (rows of `D` in this case), and we set the values at those indices equal to the corresponding value in `B` that we want.

Comment: Now that my reputation reached some, I could vote you up :)  Your solution works even for A =[2;1;8;4;7] and B= [10 1 ;11 2;19 7] Thank you.

Comment: When B's index is in 1st column and there are many more columns, this works. D = [A 999999999*ones(size(A,1),size(B,2)-1)];           % initialize your result
[tf, idx] = ismember(A, B(:,1));    % get indices of matching elements
idx(idx==0) = [];                   % trim the zeros
D(find(tf),2:size(B,2)) = B(idx,2:end);

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something (or `A` is not a vector of indices), this is actually much simpler and doesn't require `ismember` or `find` at all, just direct indexing:

```
D = [A zeros(length(A),1)-9];
D(B(:,2),2) = B(:,1)
```

which for your example matrices gives

```
D =

    1    10
    2    11
    3    -9
    4    -9
    5    19
```

Comment: Brilliant! I hate when I over-complicate things.

Comment: Yep, works fine for the example given. This would not work when A cannot be used as an index, though.

Comment: For general A, see my solution

Answer (score 2):

For general `A`:

```
A =[1;2;3;4;6]; % Note change in A
B= [10 1 ;11 2;19 5];

[aux, where] = ismember(A,B(:,2));
b_where = find(where>0);
D = [(1:length(A)).' repmat(-9,length(A),1)];
D(b_where,2) = B(where(b_where),1);
```

This gives

```
D = [ 1    10
      2    11
      3    -9
      4    -9
      5    -9 ]
```

Comment: @Luis_Mendo Thank you! But is there any reason you changed A? I am asking this to better understand your code. Thank you again.

Comment: The only reason I changed the input A is to show that my solution works even if A is not of the form [1 2 3 ...] (that is, consecutive numbers). If your A always has that form you can use the solution by @horchler, which is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

First create a temporary matrix:

```
tmp=[B; -9*ones(size(A(~ismember(A,B)))), A(~ismember(A,B))]
tmp =    
    10     1
    11     2
    19     5
    -9     3
    -9     4
```

Then use `find` to obtain the first row index with a match to elements of `A` in the second column of `tmp` (there is always a match by design).

```
D=[A, arrayfun(@(x) tmp(find(tmp(:,2)==x,1,'first'),1),A)];
D =    
     1    10
     2    11
     3    -9
     4    -9
     5    19
```

As an alternative for the second step, you could simply sort `tmp` based on its second column:

```
[~,I]=sort(tmp(:,2));
D=[tmp(I,2), tmp(I,1)]
D =
    1    10
    2    11
    3    -9
    4    -9
    5    19
```